# ActivityNotFoundException?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am getting an `ActivityNotFoundException` in the following code:

Main.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setAction("com.test.app.TEST");
     startActivity(intent); // ActivityNotFoundException
```

Manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.test.app.TEST" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 28):

I've had this issue too, as perfectly concisely described by jpahn.

the period at the front did not give any help to me.

even with exactly this (a copy of the original question including edits), I would still get  ActivityNotFoundException.

Main.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction("com.test.app.TEST");
 startActivity(intent); // ActivityNotFoundException
```

Manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.test.app.TEST" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This was resolved, after much trial-and-error, by simply adding this to the intent-filter in the manifest:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

So the final manifest file contained:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.test.app.TEST" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: That solved my problem. I didn't put action in manifest still app was running locally. bt when i uploaded it from play store i got ActivityNotFound exptn.

Comment: Adding a `<category>` solved this for me, too. I find that confusing, however, as the sample project I'm piggybacking off of doesn't use this tag in one of its activity definitions.

Comment: This is (now?) documented in https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#Receiving - `startActivity[ForResult]` automatically / secretly adds the `category.DEFAULT` to the implicit `Intent` which then fails to match the `<intent-filter>` category test because the filter must include all categories in the `Intent` (see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#CategoryTest)

Answer (score 9):

I got this error after moving an activity class from one package to another.
Clean build solved it (Project -> Clean).

Answer (score 8):

Be sure to declare your activity in the manifest.xml within the aplication:

```
<application>
    <activity android:name=".YourNewActivity"/>
</application>
```

To start the new Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(main.this, YourNewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Where *main* stands for the current activity,

Answer (score 4):

Add a . (dot) before your activity name in Android Manifest. So it should be android:name=".WordsToSpeakMainActivity"

Comment: Is this a requirement for all activities or just the default one?

Comment: Yeah this is a requirement. The attribute value should be a fully qualified class name (such as, "com.myapp.myexample.project.MyActivity"). However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a period (for example, ".MyActivity"), it is appended to the package name specified in the <manifest> element. see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nm for details.

Answer (score 4):

There two types of intents in android framework,
**1-Implicit intents** that you are using,

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.test.app.TEST" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

just add one line in intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.test.app.TEST" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

**2- Explicit Intents**

```
Intent i=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,WhereWeWantToGoActivity.class);
```

`startActivity(i);`

Answer (score 4):

I have some addition to the @Tom Pace answer. The answer is completely right, but to make it more clear:

`ActivityNotFoundException` occurs because of absence of

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Because when Android OS see this in the manifest file, understands that this activity can receive intent.

The point `ActivityNotFoundException` thrown is that, when activity(intent-creator-activity) tries to create intent for other activity(intent-receiver-activity), Android OS sees there is intent for receiver activity but receiver activity does not receive anyone. Then Android OS returns null or empty intent to intent-creator-activity. And `startActivity` throws that exception.

I have found a code from android developers to avoid this exception:

```
// Verify the original intent will resolve to at least one activity
if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```

[Android Developers: Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Answer (score 3):

To be safe you can also call your new activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, THECLASSNAME);
startActivity(intent); //
```

However, you must add the activity to the androidmanifest - and write a . in front of it, e.g.

```
<activity android:name=".YOURACTIVITYNAME"></activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

To launch an activity by a string definition, use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(
        new ComponentName("com.app", "com.app.activity.TheActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very top of your AndroidManifest.xml, you'll see the package attribute

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.example"
```

and then, in the activity tag, you'll see the name attribute:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Something"
```

Make sure that the package name and activity name, when joined together, make the full package specification of your Activity i.e.

`com.android.example` + `.Something` = `com.android.example.Something`

Otherwise, you'll get a `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem... I´m using 2 modules in a android studio project, the thing here is that I needed to add the activity to the main manifest file

```
<activity android:name="com.HeadApp.ARTry.UnityPlayerActivity"
          android:clearTaskOnLaunch="false" android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
          android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
/>
```

I had that in the unity activity manifest, I just copied the activity and paste it in the main manifest and that was it, hope it helps, eve been struggling a lot with this for the past 3 weeks