# Android: Activity not found when starting new activity using intent

Tags: android

I am trying to launch a new activity from within an existing activity however I get an activity not found exception.

Here is a stripped back version of my code and the logcat error. Any help would be really appreciated.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    startActivity(new Intent(this, TermsAndConditions.class));
}
....

}
```

NewActivity

```
public class TermsAndConditions extends Activity{

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.terms_and_conditions);

    }
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".TermsAndConditions"></activity>


    </application>
</manifest>
```

Logcat

```
04-02 16:48:43.255: E/AndroidRuntime(20856): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.app/com.example.app.TermsAndConditions}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Comment: Hmm, it looks fine here. Double check your spelling (in case there is a typo in your actual code) and try cleaning your project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActivityNotFoundException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121450/activitynotfoundexception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.example.app.TermsAndConditions"></activity>
```

and `clean` your project,

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you've told the Main Activity to send the intent but you haven't told the Terms and Conditions activity to receive the intent. You do that by, in the onCreate method in the Ts and Cs page go `getIntent()` after `setContentView`