# ActivityNotFoundException in androidManifestFile

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am developing an android application where user signs up for account. When user signs up, an email should be sent to the user gmail directly, no user interaction should be there. Please help me with this.

SignUpActivity.java

```
public class SignUp extends Activity  {

    EditText uname,email,phone;
    Button createAccount;
    SQLiteDatabase ldh;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);

        final LogindatabaseHandler ldh=new LogindatabaseHandler(this);
        //ldh=ldh.open();

        uname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        phone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        createAccount=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        createAccount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 String username=uname.getText().toString();
                 String emailid=email.getText().toString();
                 String phoneno=phone.getText().toString();

                if(username.equals("") || emailid.equals("") || phoneno.equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Information should not be blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if(!isValidPhoneno(phoneno) || !isValidEmail(emailid))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    OTP otp=new OTP();
                    String otpPass=otp.nextPassword();

                    int check=ldh.insertEntry(new Login(username, emailid,phoneno, otpPass.toString(),false));

                    if(check==1)
                    {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account created successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                       Intent gmailIntent=new Intent();
                       gmailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.android.mail.compose.ComposeActivity");
                       gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{emailid});
                        gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "hello");
                        gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"hi" );
                       startActivity(gmailIntent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent ma=new Intent(SignUp.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(ma);
                    }
                    finish();
                }               
            }
        });
    }
```

Below are the methods I have used for validation:

```
    private boolean isValidPhoneno(String phone)
    {
        String PHONE_PATTERN="[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}";

        Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(PHONE_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(phone);
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    private boolean isValidEmail(String email)
    {
        String EMAIL_PATTERN="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }


    protected void onDestroy() 
    {
        super.onDestroy();

        if(ldh!=null)
        {
            ldh.close();
        }
     }


}
```

I am getting below exception :

```
 04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.gm/com.android.mail.compose.ComposeActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
    04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
    04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
    04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
    04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847):    at com.securityapp.SignUp$1.onClick(SignUp.java:98)
    04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
    04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    04-18 17:16:06.110: E/AndroidRuntime(21847):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121450/activitynotfoundexception

Comment: Add your Activity name to manifest

Comment: You need to specify your activity into AndroidManifest file

Comment: I already have specified my activity name SignUpActivity into AndroidManifest file

Comment: Why is ur file name and class name different (SignUpActivity/SignUp ) ??

Answer (score 1):

### What you're doing

You're opening an email client with prefilled address, subject and message and allowing the user to send the email, alter it before sending or cancel it altogether.

#### Issue

```
Intent gmailIntent=new Intent();
gmailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.android.mail.compose.ComposeActivity");
```

You're assuming that the user has Gmail installed and are forcing the user to use Gmail to write an email. You cannot rely on explicitly naming the activity because Google can move it/rename it/do whatever they want with it and your app breaks. DO NOT do this.

#### Solution

Let the system pick an email client.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("message/rfc822"); // Limit to email apps.
```

Now the system will either prompt the user to pick an email client from installed apps or start the default client if the user has selected one. If there are no email clients the app will crash.

#### Solution part 2

See if there are any apps that can handle the intent before firing it.

```
if (getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null) {
    // There is an email client, start it.
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    // There are no email clients, show a toast or something.
}
```

Now the app won't crash if there are no email clients installed.

### What you're trying to do

> The email should sent using gmail directly, no user interaction should be there.

You'll want to work with Gmail API instead.

See https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android and https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#creating_messages.

If you have more problems after employing this please post another question.

Answer (score 0):

Please add try/catch surrounding

```
try{
     Intent gmailIntent=new Intent();
                                gmailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.android.mail.compose.ComposeActivity");

                                gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{emailid});
                                gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "hello");
                                gmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"hi" );
                                startActivity(gmailIntent);
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
Toast.makeText(this, "google mail app is not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You are running this code where device does not contain google mail application. So Its better to use try/catch & run this code on those device which contains google mail app.

Answer (score 0):

Using package name is not recommended as its an undocumented method. In case if the package name changes some day the code will fail.

Try this code instead

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
 "mailto", "abc@gmail.com", null));
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "This is my subject text");
 context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, null));
```

Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SENDTO