# ActivityNotFoundException, error starting an activity

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, fragment, buttonclick

This is my social fragment activity and it contains buttons view. when i click on it i want to switch from one activity to other but when i lauch it on phone and click on button it says "unfortunately app stopped" what should i do to switch from one fragment to other fragment.
here is my social frag code:
[SocialFrag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUObQ.jpg)

and i want to switch from social fragment to TechGadget Fragment on button click.

Here is Log cat 
[Log Cat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPbk3.jpg)

my App contains navigation drawer with tabhlayout and i declared buttons in one tab...while i want to open new activity when button gets clicked.

```
  **@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.social_layout,container,false);
        b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),TechGadgets.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}**
```

it reutrns error and here is log cat

```
04-28 01:07:07.300 17089-17089/com.example.android.techfnss E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.android.techfnss, PID: 17089
                                                                              android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.android.techfnss/com.example.android.techfnss.TechGadgets}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1885)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1579)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3934)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3894)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:849)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:907)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:916)
                                                                                  at com.example.android.techfnss.SocialFragment$1.onClick(SocialFragment.java:26)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-28 01:07:10.275 17089-17089/com.example.android.techfnss I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17089 SIG: 9
```

Comment: post the log cat please

Comment: and the code you are implementing to launch the 2nd activity

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times before. You need to update your question with your LogCat output. Odds are you didn't add your Activity to the manifest or something similar (make sure `TechGadgets` is an Activity). Also, use the current Activity context when creating the Intent not the Application context. Edit: It seems TechGadget may be a Fragment. Switching between Fragments is handled differently than Activities, view their documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Do not post code as a screenshot. Rather than put it as a text directly in the question.

Comment: `ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.android.techfnss/com.example.android.techfnss.TechGadgets}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` says it all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActivityNotFoundException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121450/activitynotfoundexception)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked tens of times (at least), so you could've found an answer by a Google search. However, here is how you do it...

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
button.setOnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Of course you would replace the relevant values with corresponding ones in your own code.

If you're looking for a more specific answer, ask a more specific question (with evidence that you have done research to find the answer yourself, or even at least a log trace from the crash you are getting).

Comment: This is not working as i am using SocialFrag in Tab Layout.

Comment: @Nikhil Okay. In that case, **post your code** as well, so we can all see exactly where your problem is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

use this code -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

here, `OtherActivity.class` is the name of activity that you want to go,and `Mainactivity.this` is your current activity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `setOnClickListener` on your button inside `onViewCreated` method, like this --

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
   b = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
   b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), 2nd_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the context to the Fragment when you create it and then reference it there. Or you can just use `getActivity()` instead of `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` but the first option is the best because sometimes `getActivity()` just doesn't work.
Always pass the context to the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly it says that the activity is not declared in the manifest, instead of extend fragment, extend to any type of activity and add this line to your manifest inside the `<aplication> </aplication>` body:

```
<activity android:name=".TechGadgets"></activity>
```

Example:

```
<aplication> 
... 

<activity android:name=".TechGadgets"></activity> 

...
 </application>
```

And close this ask please

Answer (score 0):

try using the below code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

and also check did you added activity in manifest

```
<activity android:name=".TechGadgets"></activity>
```