# Application crashes with ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android

I have some issues with next activity -
I made a button, and when you click on it, an intent is being made, and then you `startActivity()` with the intent.

I declared the source and the destination classes. Everytime I click the button, it closes the app and says "Unfortunately, My First Application has stopped." Any help?
Thanks in advance.

```
package com.myfirstapplication.owner.myfirstapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button nextAc;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        nextAc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextPageButton);

        nextAc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

                Bundle fromMain = new Bundle();
                fromMain.putString("BundleInfo","Look at that.");

                i.putExtras(fromMain);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Log:

```
06-15 12:10:03.673 2389-2389/com.myfirstapplication.owner.myfirstapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.myfirstapplication.owner.myfirstapplication, PID: 2389
   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myfirstapplication.owner.myfirstapplication/com.myfirstapplication.owner.myfirstapplication.SecondActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:842)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
       at com.myfirstapplication.owner.myfirstapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:76)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-15 12:10:06.361 2389-2389/com.myfirstapplication.owner.myfirstapplication I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2389 SIG: 9
```

Second activity:

```
package com.myfirstapplication.owner.myfirstapplication;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvID);

        Bundle fromMain = getIntent().getExtras();
        tv.setText(fromMain.getString("BundleInfo"));
    }

}
```

Comment: provide your log as well

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm new in this bussines. Log?

Comment: whatever logcat prints paste here

Comment: what error it actually showing ?

Comment: Have you declares the SecondActivity in manifest file.

Comment: @Anjali edited. rajan ks - it just gets out of the application and writes this message.

Comment: Check out your console log yourself: `have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` Do share the manifest file. I think that's the problem

Comment: @pbajpai21 & Vucko - New here, probaly missed that. Can you explain to me what's that exactly?

Comment: Activity is the basic fundamental component of any android app,The manifest file presents essential information about your app to the Android system, information the system must have before it can run any of the app's code. So its important to declare your activity in it. I will suggest you read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: @pbajpai21 I'll read it. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActivityNotFoundException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121450/activitynotfoundexception)

Answer (score 2):

declare your SecondActivity in your manifest file.

```
 <application>
 <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />
 </application>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have some action in the second activity. After I click the button, it's just black. Any help? Thank you!

Comment: set contentview to your activity like you did in first activity. you havent set any view to it that is why it  is showing black.@Tom

Comment: Working! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to declare your activity in Manifest.xml

Just decalre your Activity class in Manifest, will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Following Exception will occur if your forgot to add your activity in Manifest File:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myfirstapplication.owner.myfirstapplication/com.myfirstapplication.owner.myfirstapplication.SecondActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

To add new activity to manifest file simply write below line:

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"/> // if your activity is in main package
```

or

```
<activity android:name="com.myfirstapplication.owner.myfirstapplication.SecondActivity"/> // if your activity is any other package.
```

Activity will be added between your  tag.

Remember here I am not adding any action or mode in your activity. If you have certain action for your activity you can provide it over here.

Happy coding!!!

Comment: Well first of all thank you! Did it, and it didn't crush! Though I am doing some action in the second activity. Edited the main post, it's there. Any help? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Declare the activity in manifest file

```
 <activity
        android:name=".secondActivity"
        />
```

under application tag

Comment: Great, I forgot (actually, didn't know) that. Thanks!