# Error android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: only in very few devices

Tags: android, android-intent

Getting `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:` in very few (*example- Android 10, Nokia* )
devices on `onRequestPermissionsResult`  but it works perfectly fine in all other devices.

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 123:
                if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    // Permission Granted

                    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);


                } else {
                    // Permission Denied
                    Toast.makeText(Pic.this, "Gallery_Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                break;
            case 789:
                if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    // Permission Granted

                    camera_getpic();
                }
                else {
                    // Permission Denied
                    Toast.makeText(Pic.this, "Camera_Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                break;
            case 555:
                if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    // Permission Granted

                    camera_continue();
                } else {
                    // Permission Denied
                    Toast.makeText(Pic.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

    }
```

**Error.**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:4873)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult (ActivityThread.java:4914)
  at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute (ActivityResultItem.java:51)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2041)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7386)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:980)
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult (Instrumentation.java:2058)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity (Instrumentation.java:1716)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:5192)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult (FragmentActivity.java:767)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:5150)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult (FragmentActivity.java:754)
  **at com.sample.pic.Pic.onRequestPermissionsResult (Pic.java:334)**
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult (Activity.java:8264)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult (Activity.java:8114)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:4866)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ActivityNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121450/activitynotfoundexception)

Comment: Whenever you use an implicit Intent you should check for `resolveActivty` or just surround  `startActivity` with `try-catch`. This will prevent the crash . Now to make it work check which intent is failing to get `Activity` and look for resolution.

Comment: @Uuu No, i am not calling external activity on  onRequestPermissionsResult, the error seems to be for startActivityForResult.

Comment: @ADM, If implicit Intent.ACTION_PICK and MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE,  are not universal. Then, is there any way to operate the camera and gallery with something universal and applicable to most android devices?

Answer (score 0):

> **Cause**:

This exception is thrown when a `call` to Context#`startActivity` or one of its variants fails because an Activity can not be found to execute the given Intent.

You are assuming that each and every one of those ~2 billion Android devices have one or more apps with an activity matching `Intent.ACTION_MAIN` and `Intent.CATEGORY_APP_YourAppName`. There is no requirement for any of those devices to have such an activity.

> **Solution**

`Option #1:`

Wrap your startActivity() call in a `try/catch block` and catch the ActivityNotFoundException, then tell the user that you cannot find a suitable app.

`Option #2:`

Use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to see if there are any matches for the Intent. If there are none, do not call `startActivity()`, then tell the user that you cannot find a suitable app.

Comment: You meant to say Intent.ACTION_PICK and MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, these are not universal. Then, is there any way to operate the camera and gallery with something universal and applicable to most android devices?